# ANTLR dynamic scopes shareable between lexer and parser?

Tags: xml, antlr

I'm writing a little language into which I will incorporate XML literals in this fashion:

```
X ?= <element attr='blah'>text<another attr='blah /> more text</element>;
```

I'm working with the [XML grammars](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/1.+Lexer) contributed by Terrence Parr. My problem arises because the definition for PCDATA is something like `(~'<')+` which **grabs all of the other source in my modules that is outside of the XML literal**.

What I'd like to do is put a guard on the TEXT token so that it only activates when we're expecting XML.

```
PCDATA : {isInXmlFragment}?=> (~'<')+;
```

The problem is that that scope variable needs to be set from the parser, but used in the lexer. I realize that I can arrange something via a static variable in some commonly visible class, but that would be tricky if I wanted to parse multiple modules in parallel. Parr's solution has such a guard, but it only works within the context of the lexer and would only work in pure XML files with no other kinds of content.

Because I'm embedding that XML inside of a source code file, there is other text to scan that is outside of the scope of the XML parts of my lexer, yet the XML PCDATA rule piece matches all of the source, because it is so general.

Is there some safe built-in way to allow such communication between the parser and lexer? something like a scope and a way to reference the lexer dynamic scope from within the parser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... way to allow such communication between the parser and lexer?

No, not without creating a custom lexer. With the default lexer/parser from ANTLR, there's a strict separation between them: the lexer operates independently from the parser.

But, as far as I can see, you don't need this. You can recursively call lexer rules. So whenever you stumble upon that start of a tag, `<element`, you simply look ahead and either match `/>` or `>`. If it's `>` you match, try to match characters other than `<` or recursively call this entire lexer rule. At its end, there should be a `</element>`, of course.

A quick demo (without attributes to keep the grammar simple):

```
grammar Test;  

parse
 : (t=. {System.out.printf("type=\%-15s text='\%s'\n", tokenNames[$t.type], $t.text);})* EOF
 ;

XML
 : '<' Identifier ( '/>'
                  | '>' (~'<' | XML)* '</' Identifier '>'
                  )
 ;

Identifier
 : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '0'..'9')*
 ;

QAssign
 : '?='
 ;

SCol
 : ';'
 ;

Spaces
 : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {skip();}
 ;
```

If you now parser the input:

```
X ?= <element>text<another/>more<i><b>text</b></i></element>;
```

you will see the following being printed to the console:

```
type=Identifier      text='X'
type=QAssign         text='?='
type=XML             text='<element>text<another/>more<i><b>text</b></i></element>'
type=SCol            text=';'
```

As you see, XML-blocks are now being treated as single tokens. If you want to have openeing- and closing tag-tokens with PCDATA tokens in between them, you need to count the number of "opening tags" and whenever that number is more than 0, match your PCDATA token like this: `~'<'+`. With this approach, there's also no need for communication between the lexer and parser: the counter keeping track of the opening tags will be defined in the lexer.

A demo:

```
grammar Test;  

@lexer::members {
  private int openTags = 0;
}

parse
 : any* EOF
 ;

any
 : Identifier
 | QAssign
 | SCol
 | xml
 ;

xml
 : OTag (PCData | xml)* CTag
 | Tag
 ;

PCData
 : {openTags > 0}?=> ~'<'+
 ;

OTag
 : '<' Identifier ('>' {openTags++;} | '/>' {$type=Tag;})
 ;

CTag
 : '</' Identifier '>' {openTags--;}
 ;

Identifier
 : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_') ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' | '0'..'9')*
 ;

QAssign
 : '?='
 ;

SCol
 : ';'
 ;

Spaces
 : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {skip();}
 ;

fragment Tag : ;
```

Now parsing input like:

```
X ?= <x>text<y/>more<i><b>text</b></i></x>;
```

will result in the following parse:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bart. An excellent answer that is better than the solution I was looking for!